# rotate and skew deform text

Tags: css

I'm trying to mount a structure with `transform` using `rotate` and `skew` , but all the text inside are getting deform, [**check the demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5FvU/)

```
.inclined .content{ 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
    transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
}

.inclined{
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    background: #515151;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 115px;
}
```

is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the inverse transform you need to change the sign and the order of the individual transforms

```
.inclined .content{ 
    -moz-transform: skewX(-15deg) rotate(-15deg) ;
    -webkit-transform:  skewX(-15deg) rotate(-15deg);
    -o-transform:  skewX(-15deg) rotate(-15deg);
    -ms-transform:  skewX(-15deg) rotate(-15deg);
    transform: skewX(-15deg) rotate(-15deg) ;
}
.inclined{
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
    background: #515151;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 115px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/W5FvU/2/)